# Trigger fatal error in PHP 7 (non-exception)

Tags: php, api, error-handling, xampp, php-7

I need to be able to trigger a fatal error in PHP 7 that is not thrown as an exception.

According to the PHP docs, **most** of the fatal errors have been converted to exceptions. However, I can't find any docs on which ones were and were not converted.

**My Question:** What is something I can do in PHP to trigger one of the fatal errors that has not been converted to an exception?

**Reason:** I am developing a universal error handler for an API based application. I need a test case to prove it will work as I say it does.

Comment: I dont get your question sorry - you **can't catch fatal errors** in PHP. If you trigger a fatal error you script will stop executing and thats it.

Comment: If you can't I need to be able to prove that too... although the docs I have been looking at say you can.

Comment: Also, you absolutely can catch the ones that are thrown as exceptions. I can already prove that.

Comment: `try {
goto b;
} catch(Exception $e) {
    var_dump($e);
}` - Yes you can catch Exceptions, but no fatal errors.

Comment: See [`set_exception_handler()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-exception-handler.php)

Comment: That has no reference to what I said.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/123718/discussion-between-nick-j-and-xatenev).

Comment: I came here looking for the same thing.  We handle fatal errors using output buffering, and on PHP < 7 we tested for these by calling ````Triggering_E_ERROR_for_testing_purposes()````.  This now triggers an exception, so it would be good to find an example that triggers a true ````E_ERROR```` error.

Answer (score 1):

You can trigger a fatal in a number of ways, calling an undefined function is one such way and pretty simple, e.g.

```
<?php

foo();
```

```
<br />
<b>Fatal error</b>:  Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function foo() in [...][...]:4
Stack trace:
#0 {main}
  thrown in <b>[...][...]</b> on line <b>4</b><br />
```